# Nginx rewrite rule for changing domain name in image urls

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have Wordpress website which is live. In this website are a lot of posts with uploads over 200GB. I want to create in localhost development environment which I have done, but I have problems with posts images, because I don't want to download all of them and put in my localhost. So I am wondering if there is any Nginx rewrite rule which will rewrite only domain name in my image urls.

I need to rewrite this url:

`https://example.local/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/10/very-nice-picture.png`

To this one:

`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/10/very-nice-picture.png`

This is possible with Nginx or there is other better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your options:

- Use a redirection:

  ```
  location /wp-content/uploads/ {
      return 301 http://example.com$request_uri; # or use 302 to prevent redirection caching
  }
  ```
- Use transparent proxying:

  ```
  location /wp-content/uploads/ {
      proxy_pass http://example.com;
  }
  ```

You can also use remote files only in case they are missing on the local development server:

```
location /wp-content/uploads/ {
    try_files $uri @remote;
}
location @remote {
    # redirect or proxy the request as shown above
}
```

Comment: As I understand transparent proxying should be enabled on live server, right? If so, then can you show me syntax for Apache, because live website is running on it.

Comment: @RydelHouse No, this config is supposed to be used on your localhost where you serve your local WordPress site copy with nginx. nginx can issue a redirection on a file request (first config) or fetch the file from the live server itself (second config).